# Call a Function After MVC's Remote Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I want to call a function after MVC's Remote Validation returns **true**. But looks like I need another event to call that function. I have tried to call **onchange** on same  **datepicker** element but they are not called in the right sequence. I want to call validation first and **myFunction** later.

P.s. I have also gone through jquery.validate **invalidHandler** but that doesn't seem to solve the problem. As it also needs some event call.

```
<span class="fgroup">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.master.D1, new { @id = "datepicker" })

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.master.D1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</span>
```

Here is my function that I want to call after **Remote Validation** returns **true**:

```
function myFunction1() {

    var datVal = $("#datepicker").val();

    var url = "/TrM/AutoDocNoGen?date=" + datVal;
     $.ajax({
              data: datVal,
              type: "GET",
              url: url,
              success: function (data) {
                 var formValid = $("#allSaveForm").validate().form();

                 if (!formValid) {
                 return false;
                     }
                  $(".vchrNoField").val(data.NewValue);
                      },
              error: function () {

           }

      }); }
```

After return from the Ajax call I want to update the value of this field. Its very important that the validation is called first and this field below is updated afterwards.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.master.S1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "text-input-grey vchrNoField" } })
```

Comment: Maybe easier to remove the `[Remote]` attribute and handle the inputs `.blur()` event and make your own ajax calls (either call one method returning everything your need - i.e. the isValid value and the data.NewValue or call the second method in the success of the first method). You would just need to update your own error message.

Comment: That seems the only viable option. Will have to try it and make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully resolved the issue by using Jquery's **ajaxComplete** method. It bothered me a lot until I resolved it. Here is what I have done.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
    if (settings.url === "/Rules/datecheck" && xhr.responseJSON == true) {

                        var datVal = $("#datepicker").val();

                            var ur = "/TrM/AutoDocNoGen?date=" + datVal;
                            $.ajax({
                                data: datVal,
                                type: "GET",
                                url: ur,
                                success: function (data) {
                                    $(".vchrNoField").val(da.NewValue);
                                },
                                error: function () {

                                }

                            });
    }
});
```

So basically I have called my ajax request on **ajaxComplete** and adding an if statement to check if the response from the **remote validation** is returned **true**. And Tada! Its Done!